# Select query is not working while fetching data from database

Tags: php, mysql

This query is returning a false boolean value. I am unable to fetch data from database using the following login form page, using this code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>login</h2>
    <form method='post' name='login'>
      NAME  <input type='text' name='name' value=""><br><br>
      PASSWORD<input type='password' name='password'> <br><br>
      <input type='submit' name='submit'><br><br>
    </form>

    <?php
    $var=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'submit');

    function SignIn()
    {      
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = '';
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,'db');

        $n=$_POST['name'];
        $pass=$_POST['password'];

        $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='$n' and  password='$pass'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        var_dump($result);die;
    }

    if($var)
    {
      SignIn();
    }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is printing

> "bool(false)"

Whan can the problem be?

Comment: you need to take a look at the basics : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql_ function switch to mysqli_ or PDO since mysql_ is deprecated and removed from PHP 7

Comment: And use placeholders in the query, not interpolation, the way you're doing it now opens your app for SQL-Injection attacks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not working because you haven't selected any database and your `msql_connect` is not right too. `mysql_connect` accepts three parameter with server its username and password. In order to select database you have to call this function `mysql_select_db('dbname')` and then your query will work.